# How to get data from DB dynamically based on textbox input using JSP?

Tags: mysql, ajax, jsp

I am using JSP as my backend for my HTML and I want to get the customer name when I start entering the customer contact number.

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
    <script>
        function evaluation() {
            var myBox1 = document.getElementById('milk').value;
            var result = document.getElementById('result');
            var myResult = myBox1 * 35;
            result.value = myResult;
        }
    </script>

    <form action="BillValid.jsp" method="post">
        <table width="70%" cellspacing="30" color="#FFFFFF">
            <tr>
                <th>ENTER THE DETAILS</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><font color="#800000">Customercontact</font></td>
                <td><input name="cus_contact" type="text" id="contact"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><fontcolor="#800000">CustomerName</font></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="cus_name"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><font color="#800000">DayConsumption</font></td>
                <td><input id="milk" type="text" name="days_con"
                    oninput="evaluation()"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><font color="#800000">SumInRs</font></td>
                <td><input id="result" name="total"</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" name="Register"><input type="reset"
            name="reset">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

JSP:

```
 try{
    String DBuser="root";
    String DBpassword="qwerty";
    String Connection="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/online";

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    java.sql.Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(Connection,DBuser, DBpassword);
    out.println("Database Succesfully connected");            

    String CustomerName=request.getParameter("cus_name");
    String contact=request.getParameter("cus_contact");
    long customerCon=Long.parseLong(contact);  
    String dayCons=request.getParameter("days_con");
    int Consumtion=Integer.parseInt(dayCons);
    String total =request.getParameter("total");
    int totalConsume=Integer.parseInt(total);

    String sql = "select (CustomerName) from customer where CustomerContact='"+ customerCon+"'"; 
    java.sql.PreparedStatement st=conn.prepareStatement(sql); 
    java.sql.PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStatement("insert into invoice (CustomerContact ,CustomerName ,LitresConsumed ,TotalSum) values (?,?,?,?)");
    pst.setLong(1, customerCon); 
    pst.setString(2, CustomerName); 
    pst.setInt(3, Consumtion); 
    pst.setInt(4, totalConsume); 
    int i=pst.executeUpdate(); 

    if(i>0){
        response.sendRedirect("BillData.jsp");
    }else{
        response.sendRedirect("addcustomer.jsp");
    }           
}catch(Exception e){
    out.println(e);
    e.getMessage();
}
```

Comment: I am new to this JSP platform and also on stack overflow , It took me 45 mins to post this one question if someone could indent the code, the efforts will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You've to use `Ajax`. You should call a function after you entered contact number and that brings data from DB and add it in textbox.

Comment: I shall very thank full to you if you could send me the code of that function as I don't have any idea about AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO, I've got some points for you.

> I shall very thank full to you if you could send me the code of that function as I don't have any idea about AJAX.

1) That's not how this site works. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
We'll help you to resolve your issues, before that you go to try something from your end.

2) JSP is not the right place to code Java. Please check [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

You should keep your Java code in servlet. When ajax calls a request point it to sevlet and do Java code over there and return expected output.
JSP should be used to render the output.

```
package com.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String customerContact = request.getParameter("myValue");
        String customerName = "Your_Response_From_DB";
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.getWriter().write(customerName);
    }
}
```

And in your web.xml file,

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>MyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/MyServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Few corrections in your HTML,

Add ID to Customer Name (Use meaningful names).

```
<tr>
    <td><font color="#800000">Customercontact</font></td>
    <td><input name="customer_contact" type="text" id="customer_contact"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><fontcolor="#800000">CustomerName</font></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="customer_name" id="customer_name"></td>
</tr>
```

If you want to return back the same page use [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), 
download the jQuery plugin add it in your JSP page.

```
$("#customer_contact").blur(function(e){
    var contact = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type : 'post',
        url : 'MyServlet',
        data: { myValue: contact},
        success : function(data) {
           console.log(data);
           $("#customer_name").val(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Let me know if this helps.

Cheers..!